# How can I associate a subscription with a new tenant in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I have a Visual Studio Pro subscription through my work, and when I log into the Azure portal I can see a directory representing my work under my account name in the top corner.

As far as I can tell "directory" and "tenant" are used interchangeably in the Azure documentation.  So I wanted to create a new tenant as a playpen to allow me to experiment with Azure.  I was able to do that but now when I try to log in to that tenant via Azure CLI I get an error "No subscriptions found.".  This despite when I log into my work tenant it tells me I have a Visual Studio Professional Subscription.

Is it possible to set up a different tenant/directory for the same account, to use as a playpen, and somehow connect it with my VS Pro subscription?  If so, how?

Comment: `Is it possible to set up a different tenant/directory for the same account` - what do you mean by `account` - subscription or user account?

Comment: If I understand correctly, somehow you want to manage your Azure Subscription using an account that is in a different directory. Is that correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I have an account through my work which has a VS Pro subscription.  The default Directory that is shown under my account name in the top right corner of the Azure portal is my work Directory.  I would like to create another directory/tenant as a playpen, to experiment in.  I was able to create this playpen directory but when I try to log in to that new tenant via Azure CLI it says "No subscriptions found."  and I can't do anything with it.  I feel it should be possible to to create a new tenant that is usable, rather than having to create a free account, if I want to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest thing you could do is invite a user from your playpen directory by assigning them a suitable RBAC role in your VS Pro Subscription. That way when you login using your playpen directory account and try to list subscriptions, you will find your VS Pro subscription there.

[image]

Other option would be to associate your Azure Subscription to your playpen directory. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory.

Not sure if you want to do this but you can transfer your Azure Subscription to your playpen directory. Please see this link for more details if that's what you want to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription